# Lubuntu 15.10 32-bit, Can I install Windows 10 or Ubuntu 64-bit without installation media?

Tags: boot, usb, lubuntu, 64-bit, 32-bit

Long story short, I lost the hard drive that contained my windows 10 64-bit installation, and at the same time I lost my windows installer USB. I had been working on an older computer for a friend, so I had a USB installer for Lubuntu 15.10 32-bit, which I installed on my PC.
Here is the rub: unetbootin can't create a bootable usb apparently because of the brand of drive Im using, "startup disk creator" fails when installing the bootloader, and I am too much of a noob to install/compile mintstick to even try it. Does anyone have any ideas? Ideally, I'd like to reinstall windows, as I play a few games that don't work with wine, but I would also be happy if i could install Ubuntu 64-bit. As of right now, all I can think of is to borrow a friend's PC to make the USB. I don't have any burnable disks, either.
Also, a side question, in this lubuntu installation ctrl and alt seem to be mapped to "shift", so that I have 6 shift keys instead of two of each, is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

If you need Mintstick, in any Ubuntu-based distro:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tsvetko.tsvetkov/trusty-backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mintstick
```

Bur that is NOT for putting Windows on a stick. Better use a DVD for that.